# Javascript - format number to 3 decimals

Tags: javascript, html

trying to convert the number to a 3 decimals only but .toFixed(3) is being ignored. Any idea? Thx

```
output2=output2.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Number/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[8]).join("\n")*(0.00254).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap all the expression in parentheses as `toFixed` is called on `(0.00254)` instead of the multiplication result.

```
output2 = (
  output2.split("\n")
  .filter(/./.test, /Number/)
  .map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/)
     .filter(number => number != "")[8]
  )
  .join("\n")
  * 0.00254
).toFixed(3);
```

Your code seems to be very convoluted, consider refactoring.